# Something wrong in my onbeforeunload function but i couldn't find it

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Here is my working example on jsfiddle, its working on almost every browser (i tested it on IE9, Firefox, Chrome) except IE8 its acting weird: class change buttons (mavis or test1) only works if you click twice on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qq2tk/

If you put the setConfirmUnload function top of the jscript like in my example, before this function:

```
    $(".temasec").live("click", function()
```

and click the class change buttons "mavis" or "test1" its not doing anything on first click but its works on second click. This is only happening in IE8 (maybe in IE7 and IE6, didn't tested)

So if you move the setConfirmUnload function after the class change function its working normal.

What is wrong about this code? Specially for IE8 since its acting weird on IE8 only.

Thank you for your help.

Abides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like live doesnt support the change event well.

Check this out
http://api.jquery.com/live

> The paste and reset events, in addition to change when used with
>   inputs of type "file," are not fully supported by the .live() method,
>   due to issues with simulating event bubbling in Internet Explorer. In
>   these cases, the .bind() method can be used instead.

Try using [livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) insteady

Comment: Thank you for your answer, livequery is working on ie8, didn't tested on other browsers yet. I don't want to use 3.rd party plugins in my projects but i guess i have no chance. Maybe i should try bind as stated in jquery live documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using jQuery "unload" event :

$(window).unload(unloadMessage);

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but its not related about the issue you can delete those functions related about window.unload and just put live.change event on top. result is same.